# How to change Int64 to something usefull, ROS node

Tags: python, int, ros

I have this problem that I subscribe to ros node and i get Int64.
Then I'm trying to substract it from other int but i get this error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'int' and 'Int64'
```

what I'm trying to do is

```
diff = old_tick - tick
```

which is basically int = int - Int64. 
Previously I did

```
old_tick = 0
```

How can I change this Int64 to something that will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that there is confusion the fact that `std_msgs/Int16` is not a simple int type but a Python class.

It contains a single field data that contains the actual int.

So if the `tick` is `Int64` to gain access in the value, you need to use `tick.data` ([std_msgs/Int64 Message](http://docs.ros.org/api/std_msgs/html/msg/Int64.html))

Comment: Happy days Bartek, please accept this answer if it works